# Отправка, обработка и вывод формы

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Delete удалялась соответствующая строка из таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаёте файл `delete.php` в этой же папке где находится `welcome_message.php`

В нём пишите

```js
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
  die('Ошибка соединения: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id`='".(int) $_GET['id'].
  "'");
mysql_close($link); ?>
```

И вместо

```
<button>Delete</button>
```

Пишите

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?=$val->id?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Чет не работает

Comment: Выше скрины я скинул

Comment: Вы создали файл delete.php?

Comment: И оберните этот код как подобается <? код ?>

Comment: <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
  die('Ошибка соединения: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id`='".(int) $_GET['id'].
  "'");
mysql_close($link); ?>

Comment: Да я создал фаил он лежит в одной папке со вьюхой

Comment: Проверяйте url, всё должно работать

Comment: Можно ли это как-то через button или input провернуть?

Comment: <button onClick="location.href='delete.php?id=<?=$val->id?>'">Delete</button>

Comment: Можете написать пожалуйста только удаление одной строки, я попытаюсь вникнуть как это работает. Напишу функцию Delete и сошлюсь на нее

Comment: он одну строку и удаляет

Comment: А можно ли это провернуть через unset?

Comment: А причем здесь unset - эта функция удаляет переменную но не строку в бд